# Why does the 'role' attribute have no "container" value?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

```html
<div class= "container" role= "grid">
```

For the `role` attribute of div.container, I choose the `grid` value.

Why is no `container` value?

```html
<!-- =layout: start -->
<div class="container" role="grid">
    <div class="row" role="row">
        <aside class="col col-aside" role="complementary">
            <h2>aside</h2>
        </aside>
        <main class="col col-main" role="main">
            <h2>main</h2>
            <!-- =panel: start -->
            <div class="panel" role="region">
                <h3>panel</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- =panel: end -->
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- =layout: end -->
```

Comment: Seems like you are overusing the ARIA role which may have more of a negative impact rather than improving accessibility

Answer (score 3):

You can read more about ARIA authorized roles in the [ARIA in HTML reference doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#allowed-aria-roles-states-and-properties)

There is no "container" role. You're perfectly right.

Why? Because you don't have to give a role for elements used purely for decoration purpose like in your case a wrapper `div` for non interactive elements.

See for instance the `grid` definition:

> A grid is an interactive control which contains cells of tabular data arranged in rows and columns, like a table.

This is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

ARIA landmark roles (via the `region` value), are similar to what you're describing in that they *do* allow you to create and name your own containers that assistive technology can then identify and navigate directly to.

```
  <div role="region" aria-labelledby="region1"> 
    <h2 id="region1">Title for Region Area 1</h2> 
      ... some content ...
  </div>
```

The caveat here is that you should only create named regions where they're actually useful for users of assistive technology. Don't go around creating landmarks for every little thing, because they'll be annoying.

It's also worth noting that the title of the region should be useful and make sense without additional context. A good example would be "*Search*". A bad example would be "*Region 1*".

The image below shows what a screen reader (NVDA) user would see when navigating by roles. All of the roles used are default values, with the exception of `search`.
[image: NVDA Elements List Window]